# Change the jQuery calendar date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change the selected date(today's date) in calendar?

**Example** 
In this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gvAbv/8/), when I click on the ... (three dots) a calendar appears and the selected date is today's date. When I select another date like 6, the 2nd time I click on the text box, the calendar appears but there are yellow shades on two dates: today's and the one I selected (6th). This is what i want to change: when one date is selected, the next time only that date should be shaded only. I hope you understand what I want to say.

Thanks in advance.

here is my script

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
   $("#fullDate").datepicker({

        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calender.jpg",
        buttonImageOnly: true, 


        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#year').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
        $('#month').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
        $('#day').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
    }
    });
 });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use defaultDate. Here is an example:

```
$('.datepicker').datePicker({ defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate("d m y", "31 8 2009") });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this example

```
//Set DatePicker to October 3, 2008
$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
```

use defaultDate instead of setDate, if setDate does not work

Link [reference](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-setDate)
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516199/jquery-datepicker-change-today-date)