# How to set server machine date as current date in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

Here's my code and its result:

```
$(function () {        
        $('.temp').datepicker({
            showWeek: true,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            defaultDate: "27/03/2018",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
        $(".temp").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", "26/03/2018");
    });
```

[image]

I want to set my server computer date  *26/03/2018* instead of client machine date  *19/03/2018*.

I tried both functions *defaultDate* and  *setDate* but it's not working. It still shows the current date as *19/03/2018*.

How to set server machine date as current date in jquery datepicker?

Comment: What server are you using? The server must write the date in the HTML somewhere at least.

Comment: i am using .Net framework (MVC 5 ) and project deploy on IIS server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666321/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-highlighted-today-date

Answer (score 0):

You can use string quantifiers for your default date like:

```
defaultDate: "+3d" // + 3 days
```

You may also want to set your min and max dates so the date you want resides inside the date range.

```
 minDate: "01/01/1901",
 maxDate: "01/01/2099",
```